# ODATA Associations inside SAPUI5 m.table

Tags: data-binding, odata, associations, sapui5

My Associated Data Models:

A:

> Id, BId, Text, Date, bla, blub

B:

> Id, Text, Description, da, dam

Now I want to have a Table, preferably `sap.m.table`, of A with the text of B in it.

Table rows:

> Text, B.Text, Date, bla, blub

For now I have a formatter in which I make an `ODataModel.read()` with the association, but that feels kind of clunky.

Is there a way to bind the association directly in the XML of the table?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: the cardinality of A to B is n:1, yes there is a navigation property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the associated entity is :1 you should be able to directly access with a path `{ParentProp/ChildProp}`

The example below illustrates this scenario, let me know if that works for you. In case the data is not available you could use `$expand` to bring that data along with your parent entity.

https://output.jsbin.com/sazuqad/2